# Are strings interleaved when using ap_log_error() in a prefork apache?

Tags: apache, logging, error-log, apr

Using `printf()` and `fprintf()` from an apache module in a pre-fork apache seems to interleave the logs in error_log. Would using `ap_log_error()` instead of, say, `fprintf(stderr, ...)` fix the interleaving?